# PHP displaying tags in browser?

Tags: php

When I create a php file and try to echo something to the browser I get back everything including the code that shouldn't be displayed. I'm wondering if I have turned off a Apache modules or something. Does  anyone have any idea ? the example below display. 
The PHP tags and the echo command.

file:///C:/wamp/www/Training/text.php

```
<?php

echo "Anthing";

?>
```

Comment: You should first install Web server and PHP module and then you will be able to run your files on Localhost

Comment: This is already done.

Comment: Don't use `file:` protocol/path, use `localhost/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are typing file location in browser. You must use your local web-server address. Try typing this in URL bar of browser.

localhost/Training/text.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your file by a webserver path. Like `127.0.0.1/Training/text.php` or `localhost/Training/text.php`.

If you are accesing this file like `file:///C:/wamp/www/Training/text.php`, browser will not know how to execute `<?php` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The URL itself `file:///C:/` indicates that the file itself is being displayed, not the output.
Start your webserver and point your browser to `http://localhost/Training/text.php`